# Limits with x power

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the basic way to solve this kind of limits? How to use $e$ in this case?

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}\right)^x
\end{align}

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Put all expressions in the form $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$. Change variable $X=\frac1x$, and use $\lim_{X\to0}X\ln X=0$.

Comment: Determine the limits of the logs.

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

$$\frac{ax+b}{ax+c}$$ can be written as

$$1+\frac{b-c}{ax+c}$$ and with a change of variable

$$\left(\frac{ax+b}{ax+c}\right)^x=\left(\left(1+\frac{b-c}t\right)^t\right)^{1/a}\left(1+\frac{b-c}t\right)^{-c/a}.$$

This solves the three first cases.

The fourth case is not really an undeterminate form.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, consider $$A=\left(\frac{2 x+1}{2 x-1}\right)^x$$ Take logarithms $$\log(A)=x \log\left(\frac{2 x+1}{2 x-1}\right)=x \log\left(1+\frac{2 }{2 x-1}\right)$$ Now, since $x$ is large, using equivalents $$\log\left(1+\frac{2 }{2 x-1}\right)\sim \frac{2 }{2 x-1}\sim\frac1x$$ Then $???$

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example:
\begin{align}\ln\biggl(\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}\biggr)^x&=x\ln\biggl(\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}\biggr)=x\ln\left(\frac{1+\dfrac1{2x}}{1-\dfrac1{2x}}\right)=x\biggl(\ln\Bigl(1+\dfrac1{2x}\Bigr)-\ln\Bigl(1-\dfrac1{2x}\Bigr)\biggr)\\
&=x\biggl(\frac1{2x}+o\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)+\frac1{2x}+o\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)\biggr)=x\biggl(\frac1{x}+o\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)\biggr)=1+o(1).
\end{align}
Hence $\;\biggl(\dfrac{2x+1}{2x-1}\biggr)^x\to \mathrm e$.